# Can I target the text of this href without wrapping it

Tags: html, css

so I'm trying to keep the code down to a minimum is there a way I can add a margin to the text of this href without moving the font awesome icon down also. The only way I can see to do it would be to wrap a span tag around it and setting that to have a margin.

```
<a id="btn" class="green-btn"><i class="social fa fa-share fa-2x"></i>Share</a>
```

Comment: you did answer you own question... in your question

Comment: I asked was there another way to my solution in which case the answer would be no?

Comment: setting a margin to the icon would be an option. but i would use the span tag

Answer (score 1):

If you want space betweeen the icon and the text try this:

```
.green-btn .fa-share{
    margin-right:5px /*or your custom value*/
    }

    or 

    #btn .fa-share{
    margin-right:5px /*or your custom value*/
    }
```